# What are those white circles on the desktop in Gnome 3?

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop

I have Fedora 20 with GNOME 3.10.2.

On the desktop background (i.e. where the wallpaper is), there are five small white circles centered at the very bottom of the screen. The first is filled, the others are not. I can click those circles, thereby changing which one is filled, like a radio button.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what those circles are supposed to do, and it's starting to drive me crazy. Clicking and thus changing which circle is filled does nothing I can perceive, and there seems to be no configuration option anywhere that has anything to do with them.

What are those things? Is there any way to get rid of them?

Edit: I made a screenshot of my desktop with no programs running. You can see the dot/circle thingies at the bottom.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit 2: In case it helps, the circles do not show up in the overview.

Comment: Sounds odd, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Just added one. Oddly, I cannot find any mention of these thingies on any of the Gnome help pages. Also I tried and found that they persist regardless of if I set a wallpaper, a picture or a solid colour as background.

Comment: It looks as if it's some kind of welcome/intro application that launches as part of Gnome that perhaps isn't loading or rendering properly. I'd suggest logging on (no apps running) and then working through the list of running processes (running under your username) and killing ones that I don't recognise. If you kill the right one, the circles/dots will probably disappear. Once identified it should be relatively simple to stop it loading in future with the Gnome desktop. This might take several logons/reboots, as if you kill the wrong process, it might crash/kill your session.

Comment: From a console use `ps -u monk` (replace monk with your username) to list processes running under your username. You can then use the command `kill <pid>` where <pid> is the PID reported by the ps command for a particular process.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Bryan, you solved it! I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that before posting here.

The culprit was gnote, which I don't even use but which Gnome decided I needed anyway. I still don't know what the circles would ultimately do, but by preventing gnote from starting at login I was able to make them disappear.

Comment: You appear to have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to edit the question and accept the correct answer, but you'll need to get Bryan to post it as an answer first, or post a self-answer.  For the moment I have edited your answer so it stands on its own.